# How to design a form in String Buffer

Tags: java, html

- I have a requirement of designing a form within a StringBuffer.
- I have a form with one text field and one delete button. the form will we submitted to the same jsp page and the value of text field is again populated in the text field.
- The button **Add Additional Info**  functionality is to add new row in the form that too is a one text field & delete button.

This is the form.

**coding done for the form is as below:**

```
buffer.append("<TR><TD class=\"formdata1\" align=\"center\" colspan=\"1\"><input name=\"_addInfo"+        rowValue +"\" type=\"text\" class=\"formdata2\"size=\"90\" maxlength=\"100\" value="+ **tempInfoValue** + " ></input>\n");
buffer.append("<input type=\"button\" class=\"button\" onClick=\"deleteLastAddInfoLine(" + formName +",'"+ rowValue + "'," +totalNumberOfRows+ ");\" value=\"Delete\" ></input></td>\n");
buffer.append("  </TR>\n");
rowValue++;
}
buffer.append(" <TR>      <TD class=\"buttonrow\" class=\"formlabel\" colspan=\"6\" ><input type=\"button\" class=\"button\" onClick=\"addInfoLine(" + formName +",'"+ actionValue + "'," +totalNumberOfRows+ ");\" value=\"Add Additional Info\" ></input>\n ");

buffer.append("  </TR>\n");
buffer.append(" </table>  ");
```

Issue is: 
If input value is: **abc'xyz** then after clicking on Add Additional Info button the same value should be populated. 
but the output value populated is: abc

---

'xyz -> this content is removed.

- Here, this tempInfoValue is populated again.
- So it can contain anything like '(singlecode/doublecode)/:/;/./ or etc.
- So how should i write the code that when again it is populated then it will not change the value of text field.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer, it was replaced by StringBuilder ten years ago.

Comment: Yes Peter..u r right. The code was developed 10 years ago only. We are just doing some enhancements.